# dynamixel_controller manager wrong package prefix

Tags: dynamixel, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, controller-manager, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm working with the dynamixel MX-64AT servos.
Using a Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS kinetic version 1.12.12
Up until now I had no problem to get them up and running. Then I switched computers and now I get an error message whenever I try to start the controller_manager. Weirdly this problem now also occurs on the computer that up until now I had never had any troubles with.
Basically the error can be reproduced when following this tutorial : http://wiki.ros.org/dynamixel_controllers/Tutorials/ConnectingToDynamixelBus
I do have the baud rate and id set to the right values and also checked that the USB port has the correct read and write permissions.
Also I read that it could be related to faulty cables, but I also changed all of them several times, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Whenever I try to execute roslaunch my_dynamixel_tutorial controller_manager.launch I get these error messages saying something about a invalid response and wrong prefix error.

```
    1517479067.955998897 INFO [dynamixel_serial_proxy.py:158(__find_motors) [topics: /motor_states/pan_tilt_port, /rosout, /diagnostics] pan_tilt_port: Pinging motor IDs 1 through 25...
1517479070.048603057 ERROR [dynamixel_serial_proxy.py:187(__find_motors) [topics: /motor_states/pan_tilt_port, /rosout, /diagnostics] Exception thrown while getting attributes for motor 10 - Invalid response received from motor 10. Wrong packet prefix []
1517479070.175116062 ERROR [dynamixel_serial_proxy.py:187(__find_motors) [topics: /motor_states/pan_tilt_port, /rosout, /diagnostics] Exception thrown while getting attributes for motor 10 - Invalid response received from motor 10. Wrong packet prefix ['\xff']
1517479070.177623033 ERROR [dynamixel_serial_proxy.py:187(__find_motors) [topics: /motor_states/pan_tilt_port, /rosout, /diagnostics] Exception thrown while getting attributes for motor 10 - Invalid response received from motor 10. Wrong packet prefix ['\xff', '\n']
1517479070.194986104 ERROR [dynamixel_serial_proxy.py:187(__find_motors) [topics: /motor_states/pan_tilt_port, /rosout, /diagnostics] Exception thrown while getting attributes for motor 10 - Invalid response received from motor 10. Wrong packet prefix ['\xc0']
1517479070.321788072 ERROR [dynamixel_serial_proxy.py:187(__find_motors) [topics: /motor_states/pan_tilt_port, /rosout, /diagnostics] Exception thrown while getting attributes for motor 10 - Invalid response received from motor 10. Wrong packet prefix []
1517479070.340946912 ERROR [dynamixel_serial_proxy.py:187(__find_motors) [topics: /motor_states/pan_tilt_port, /rosout, /diagnostics] Exception thrown while getting attributes for motor 15 - Invalid response received from motor 15. Wrong packet prefix ['0']
1517479070.357222080 ERROR [dynamixel_serial_proxy.py:187(__find_motors) [topics: /motor_states/pan_tilt_port, /rosout, /diagnostics] Exception thrown while getting attributes for motor 15 - unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'float' and 'int'
1517479070.504827976 INFO [dynamixel_serial_proxy.py:211(__find_motors) [topics: /motor_states/pan_tilt_port, /rosout, /diagnostics] pan_tilt_port: Found 1 motors - 1 MX-64 [15], initialization complete.
```

Weirdly enough, sometimes it will still recognize both motors and be able to work with them.
To me it sounds a bit as if something with the communication is going wrong, but to be honest I can't figure out, where it's going wrong. I would appreciate any help.

Best Regards,
B.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281521/dynamixel_controller-manager-wrong-package-prefix/) by [Cataglyphis](https://answers.ros.org/users/33511/cataglyphis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello :)

ROBOTIS provides official opensource repository as [ROBOTIS-GIT](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT)?

In this repository, you can find [Dynamixel-Workbench](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/dynamixel-workbench) to control all series of DYNAMIXELS. Because it is official package for DYNAMIXEL, you can get a proper solution when you faced some problems.

This is WIKI page for DYNAMIXEL and introduced packages.

[WIKI for DYNAMIXEL](http://emanual.robotis.com/)

[WIKI for Dynamixel-Workbench](http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/software/dynamixel/dynamixel_workbench/)

Enjoy with it!

Darby

---

Originally posted by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) with karma: 811 on 2018-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-02-22**:
I believe that this should be a comment instead of an answer as this doesn't answer the question. Instead, it just points to a wiki and GitHub repo.

**Comment by [Cataglyphis](https://answers.ros.org/users/33511/cataglyphis/) on 2018-02-22**:
Hello,
my problem is, that it did work well for a while and I have some work already done in the old framework. If possible I would like to avoid redoing all that work to be compatible to the new package.

**Comment by [Cataglyphis](https://answers.ros.org/users/33511/cataglyphis/) on 2018-02-22**:
In particular with the old package it was very easy to control 3 servos. I tried the workbench, but in the tutorials it only describes working with 2 servos and I couldn't find a way to generalize this to 3 or more motors without rewriting big chunks of the code, following a trail of libraries etc.

**Comment by [Darby Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30440/darby-lim/) on 2018-03-19**:
The new version of Dynamixel supports 3 or more motors connect in tutorial.
You can download in github (not `apt-get install`)

**Comment by [Cataglyphis](https://answers.ros.org/users/33511/cataglyphis/) on 2018-03-26**:
Thanks for the tip, I will look into it